# Центрирование элемента относительного другого

Tags: css

Есть 2 элемента, кнопка и span. У span абсолютное позиционирование, как сделать, чтобы span был центрирован относительно кнопки?

```
 <button class="button_balance" style="width:265px; left:970px; top:-161px; position:relative"/>Get Balance</button>
        <span id="amount" style="position:absolute; margin-left:1045px; margin-top:200px; color:red; font-size:30px"></span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем такое извращение в стилях? О.о Дайте пример, что вы хотите получить, в виде картинки.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 добавил картинку

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нужно центрировать, относительно кнопки

Comment: На будущее, не используйте абсолютное позиционирование для построения самой разметки страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант, обернуть это всё `div`ом, ему задать положение и ширину самой кнопки и выставить `text-align: center;`, тем самым мы получим такой результат:

```html
<div style="width: 150px; text-align: center;">
  <button type="button" style="width: 150px;">Ваша кнопка</button>
  <br><br>
  <span>Текст по центру</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

span должен быть внутри кнопки, чтобы центрироваться относительно нее. если не внутри, то центрироваться будет относительно контейнера (если задать).

но для этой задачи абсолютное позиционирование - грех. Просто сделайте это флексами.

Comment: А не смущает то, что к `button` стили добавлены?

Comment: и что?
спану на них хвостом накласть.

Comment: Я про наследственность. `span` примет стили `button` и получится [вот что](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/ah8dbft6/1/)

Comment: А, понял. Ну, во-первых, надо заресетить стили для спана. А во-вторых, спан заодно от баттона и функционал приобретет (действие при клике на кнопку распространится и на спан), так что я этот вариант как рабочий даже не рассматривал, чисто привел как пример ;) Поэтому и не понял что ваш комментарий относится именно к такой ситуации =)

Answer (score 1):

Через **flexbox**:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 265px;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button>Get balance</button>
  <span>12345</span>
</div>
```